# Evaluating a GROOVY expression while debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm trying to debug a simple groovy project in eclipse, code is as simple as this:

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
println list.collect { it + 1 }
```

And it executes fine; only when I try to evaluate this part:

```
list.collect { it + 1 }
```

in the display view (or inspect it in the editor: shift+crl+i) I'm shot at with the following message:

```
list.collect { it + 1 }
    Evaluation failed. Reason(s):
        org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException (id=115)
```

Anyone ever had this issue, and knows how to fix it? Thanks a ton.

Using STS 2.5.2 (Eclipse 3.6.1r361), Groovy 1.7.8, jdk1.6.0_24; Groovy-Eclipse Plugin 2.1.2.xx.20110218

And btw, I think the problem didn't occur back when I was using sts 2.3.x (eclipse 3.5.x)

Comment: This question is best asked on the Groovy-Eclipse mailing list.

Comment: Thanks, Peter, I will. I just thought this could be something common and easy to fix..

Comment: @z_free I'd encourage you to keep posting to SO for questions like this. I come here before any mailing lists.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create closures in the display view.  Instead, you will need to write this out in a for loop.  Eg-

```
def newList = []
for (elt in list) {
  newList << elt++
}
print newList
```

This is a vm limitation since under the hood, a closure is represented by a class declaration.  There is no easy way to inject a class generated by the display view into the running application.

Comment: Yeah, I just read on the groovy-eclipse plugin web site that you can evaluate code snippets in the display view, but should use java syntax and cast all groovy objects accordingly. Weird, 'cause I'm almost sure I saw this kinda thing being done in a vmware presentation. Anyway, Intellij Idea does the trick for the most part, so I started using it instead. Thanks, Andrew :)

Comment: That part of the website is outdated.  If you use SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) (not Groovy-Eclipse stand-alone), you can evaluate groovy expressions in the display view when paused on a groovy stack frame.